# in infopath, how to display message in multiline textbox

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, form

There is a field which name is ID (textbox). I have SharePoint list and created data connection to (retrive data)and display in Multilined textbox. and it is happening.

But my question is when user enter ID if it is not present in SP list then it would be diplay message in multiline textbox.

How can I acheived this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rule on the multi-line TextBox, when the ID is not present, set the TextBox to your message:
[image]

[Add rules for performing other actions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-5322d726-b787-4e5f-8d37-ba6db68b451d#__toc269451433)